# Adobe Illustrator export PNG Sequence

Tags: export, png, adobe-illustrator

I just started using Illustrator, and I'm wondering if it is possible to export every single layer to a png file. I can't find an answer on the web.

I found 1 script that should work, but nothing happens with that one.. 
http://www.ericson.net/files/illustrator-scripts/MultiExporter.jsx

Any ideas how it could work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution already
http://www.arcticmill.com/2012/08/export-layers-as-png-files-from-illustrator-in-multiple-resolutions.html
here you can find a script that'll work

Comment: That link doesnt exist any more :(